# how to see if column name matches given array in yii

Tags: php, yii

How do I find if the column name matches if I have an array?
So I have a loop, the name of the column goes from 1 to 6 at the end. Looking to remove the image on click.

This doesn't work. It also doesn't work if I change `$i` to `1` in  `$product_id= "product_gallery_"+[$i];`

```
 for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++)
        {
        $product_img= "product_gallery_"+[$i];
            if($model->getAttributeLabel($product_id)==$image_attr) // not sure about $image_attr either, it was passed from view
            {   
            $filename = $model->$product_img;
            unlink($path.$filename);
            $model->product_gallery_[$i] = "default.png";
            $model->save();
            echo "removed";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why have you got square brackets around the $i? and + is not the PHP concatenation operator

Comment: If you want to concatenate "product_gallery_" with [$i] you should use a '.' not a '+' I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP uses the . (dot) as the concatenation operator not the + sign.

Also the [] (square brackets) are used to address array elements by key not to access individual variables eg `$variable[$key]` to access the `$key` element of the `$variable` array

```
for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++)
{
    $product_img= "product_gallery_".$i;
    if($model->getAttributeLabel($product_id)==$image_attr) // not sure about $image_attr either, it was passed from view
    {   
        $filename = $model->$product_img;
        unlink($path.$filename);
        $model->$product_img = "default.png";
        $model->save();
        echo "removed";
    }
}
```